# How can I fade in/out a UILabel on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-animation, uilabel

I want to be able to fade in/out a couple UILabel's on my UITableView cell. How can I achieve this using CoreAnimation or an animation block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
someLabel.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

More specifically, if you've got your labels added to the cell’s content view with a particular `tag` set for each one, you can do something like

```
[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2].alpha = 0;
[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1].alpha = 1;
```